# Is there valid "use cases" for Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++11, undefined-behavior

I have found a piece of code which has UB, and was told to leave it in the code, with a comment that states it is UB. Using MSVC2012 only.

The code itself has a raw array of `Foo` objects, then casts that array to `char*` with `reinterpret_cast<char*>` and then calls `delete casted_array` (like this, not delete[]) on it.

Like this:

```
Foo* foos = new Foo[500];

char* CastedFoos = reinterpret_cast<char*>(foos);

delete CastedFoos;
```

Per the Standard 5.3.5/3 this is clearly Undefined Behavior.

Apparently this code does what it does to avoid having to call destructors as an optimisation.

I wondered, is there actually places where leaving UB in the code could be considered *valid*?

Also, as far as I'm concerned, leaving the above in code is not smart, am I right?

Comment: Technically, UB is an UB. A particular implementation might demonstrate a particular recurring behavior for a type of UB but that does not make the behavior guaranteed no portable.

Comment: Almost all implementation-specific extensions are undefined behaviour in standard C++, and there are definitely legitimate reasons for using extensions.

Comment: Never mind the question, but why is this necessary? If `Foo` doesn't have anything useful to destruct, just give it a trivial destructor. And if it does, and you accept the leakage, then why bother freeing the memory at all?

Comment: @KerrekSB can't afford the leakage, the memory must be destroyed.

Comment: I guess changing `~Foo()` to do nothing made too much sense, and `::operator delete(foos)` was too simple? ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant apparently `Foo` only has a default dtor. So perhaps this "optimisation" is not really what it looks like

Comment: In any event, I would prefer placement-new object creation. Then you can free the memory properly, and whether or not it is UB is "confined" to whether the relevant destructors have any effects. (But of course in a loop and [never via array-placement-new](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425/596781).)

Comment: To quote Andrei Alexandrescu, two words: "Contact headhunter."

Comment: I am very interested to see what ~Foo does that would warrant the desire to avoid it being called. I assume it is doing more then it really needs to or should be doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard defines "undefined behaviour" as follows:

> behavior for which this standard imposes no requirements

So if you want your code to be portable to different compilers and platforms, then your code should not depend on undefined behavior, because what the programs (that are produced by different compilers compiling your code) do in these cases may vary.

If you don't care about portability, then you should check if your compiler documents how it behaves under the circumstances of interest.  If it doesn't document what it does (and it doesn't have to), beware that the compiler could change what it does without warning between different versions.  Also note that its behaviour may be non-deterministic.  So for example it could crash 1% of the time, which you may not notice in ad-hoc testing, but will come back and bite you later when it goes into production.  So even if you are using one compiler, it may still be a bad idea to depend on undefined behavior.

With regard to your specific example, you can rewrite it to achieve the same effect (not calling destructor, but reclaiming memory) in a way that does not result in undefined behaviour.  Allocate a `std::aligned_storage` to hold the Foo array, call *placement new* to construct the Foo array on the `aligned_storage`, then when you want to deallocate the array, deallocate the `aligned_storage` without calling placement delete.

Of course this is still a terrible design, may cause memory leaks or other problems depending on what `Foo::~Foo()` was supposed to do, but at least it isn't UB.

Answer (score 7):

It depends entirely on your perspective.

Take an extreme example: in C++03, threads were undefined behavior. As soon as you had more than one thread, your program's behavior was no longer defined by the C++ standard.

And yet, most people would say threads are *useful*.

Of course, multithreading may have been UB according to the C++ standard, but individual compilers didn't *treat* it as undefined. They provided an additional guarantee that multithreading is going to *work* as you'd expect.

When talking about C++ in the abstract, UB has no uses whatsoever. How could it? You don't know what could or would happen.

But in specific applications, specific code compiled by specific compilers to run on specific operating systems, you may sometimes know that a piece of UB is (1) safe, and (2) ends up having some kind of beneficial effect.