# Malloc seemingly using less memory than new[]

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc

Could there be any reason why:

```
new X[n];
```

would consume more memory as compared to:

```
X* x = reinterpret_cast<X*>(malloc(n * sizeof(X))
for(X* p = x; p != x + n; ++p)
    new (p) X();
```

for multiple copies of multiple n's?

I am seeing evidence of this.

Comment: Overloaded `X::operator new' ??

Comment: What's the evidence. How are you measuring?

Comment: `std::vector` wors exactly the way you suggest. In fact, you should consider array-`new` an antipattern.

Answer (score 5):

Of course: Array-new is allowed to allocate *more* memory than just the space for the objects, and usually will do so. When you say `delete [] x;`, how would the implementation know how many destructors to call?

See 5.3.4/10:

> A *new-expression* passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type `std::size_t`. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; **it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array.**

The Itanium ABI is [specific about the use of array cookies](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#array-cookies):

```
|<-- offset -->|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+
|(padding)  N  |   a[0]   |   a[1]   |   ...   |  a[N-1] |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+
^              ^
|              +---- T * a = new T[N]
|
+----  return value of `operator new(sizeof(T) * N + offset)`
```

Comment: Won't any implementation of `malloc` store the same information?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I was thinking about but I didn't dare to question KerrekSB's knowledge...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's different. Of course somewhere internally someone will know how much memory is allocated for a given pointer. But that's unrelated. The memory allocator doesn't know about objects.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then what's the extra information needed? `n` objects -> `n` destructors, isn't it that simple? (So I suspect it isn't...)

Comment: @H2CO3: And given `x`, how do you know the value of `n`?

Comment: I guess that's because the actual block of memory might have some wasted space. And so you cannot calculate n by dividing the total block size by the element size.

Comment: For a fun and insane related question, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425/596781). (A DR for this is in the pipeline.)

Comment: @KerrekSB 1. In the case of `malloc()`: given `p`, how do you know the size of the allocated memory? 2. Thanks for the link, reading.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's not our problem, that's the business of the memory allocator. Don't confuse memory and objects!

Comment: @KerrekSB I think I start to get this. Here, is the number of destructors to be called something that is to be visible externally?

Comment: @H2CO3: Not "externally" as such, but `delete [] x;` has to work. There's no other direct way for a user to inspect the size of the array, though (and if you check the Itanium ABI, in some cases there isn't even a cookie at all).