# Allocator specialized for array types in c++14?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, c++14, allocator

Why isn't there an array template specialization for std::allocator<T[]> in c++14?

When playing around trying to specialize std::allocator<T[]> myself I hit a dead-end when implementing the construct() and destroy() method. Is this the reason? Why then have construct() and destroy() part of std::allocator<>?

```
template <T>
class allocator <T[]> {

    // ...most is similar for std::allocator<>...

    template <class U, class... Args>
    void construct( U *p, Args&&.. args)
    {
        // what to write for array construction?
        // Could be std::initializer_list<T> or uniform initalizer list.
        // Want to pass on to constructor somehow.
        // ::new ((void *)p) [] U(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }

    template <class U>
    void destroy( U* p )
    {
        // no-op.
    }
};
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Remember also that placement array new can be rather [problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer).

Comment: Also note that specializing `std::allocator` like this is illegal, since `T` is not (guaranteed to be) a user type.

Comment: Look at how your Standard Library implementation's `std::vector` uses the allocator. It does support dynamic arrays, but not directly. This makes sense to me since the allocator does not have to deal with those details but just provides the minimal functionality required.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: None of what follows makes sense. Don't do this at home. Don't mix arrays and dynamic allocation.** The following serves merely as a mental exercise in spelling out very long template names.

The standard allocator does indeed not provide for array construction, but you can easily build your own allocator that does. Note that we're free to provide `construct()`/`destroy()` mechanisms as we please:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct array_allocator : std::allocator<T>
{
    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<C>::value>::type construct(C * p, Args &&... args)
    {
        ::new (static_cast<void *>(p)) C { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    }

    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<C>::value>::type construct(C * p, Args &&... args)
    {
        ::new (static_cast<void *>(p)) C(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<C>::value>::type destroy(C * p)
    {
        using U = typename std::remove_extent<C>::type;
        using UAT = typename std::allocator_traits<array_allocator>::template rebind_traits<U>;
        typename std::allocator_traits<array_allocator>::template rebind_alloc<U> ra(*this);

        for (std::size_t i = 0, e = std::extent<C>::value; i != e; ++i)
        {
            UAT::destroy(ra, std::addressof((*p)[e - i - 1]));
        }
    }

    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<C>::value>::type destroy(C * p)
    {
        p->~C();
    }
};
```

Here is a usage example, allocating and constructing arrays of 13 `int`.:

```
using T = int[13];
using TA = array_allocator<T>;
using TAT = std::allocator_traits<TA>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    TA a;
    T * p = TAT::allocate(a, 2);   // allocates space for two T's

    TAT::construct(a, p, 1, 2, 3);
    TAT::construct(a, p + 1, 4, 5, 6);

    for (T * q = p; q != p + 2; ++q)
        for (int * r = *q; r != *q + 13; ++r)
            std::cout << *r << "\n";

    TAT::destroy(a, p + 1);
    TAT::destroy(a, p);

    TAT::deallocate(a, p, 2);
}
```

As linked in the comments, though, beware that it's impossible to prove that the inherited `allocate` function returns the correct amount of memory.

Comment: Pretty sure you're supposed to destroy them in the opposite order they're constructed...  `for(int i=std::extent<C>::value; i-->0; )`

Comment: I think you have undefined behavior here, as `allocate` reserves enough room for two `int[13]` sequentially in memory, but "Array placement-new requires unspecified overhead in the beginning of the buffer", which would be between the two elements for the second array, so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, the whole thing is bogus and nonsense anyway. You can't allocate the correct amount of memory, and there is no matching "delete" operation to go with the placement-`new` -- unlike in the scalar case, where it's `p->~C()`, there's nothing like that for arrays. `new T` is really a weird thing when `T` is an array type, since it mixes up static and dynamic typing.

Comment: Actually, wait, I think this can be done, in a completely absurd manner, simply by rewriting the array allocation/construction/etc from scratch.

Comment: @moo: yeah, you could unroll the `construct` code as well... And emulate value initialization for missing args in the pack...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56676/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-kerrek-sb).

Comment: Why do you use SFINAE instead of partial specialization / SFINAE on method level instead of SFINAE on the class template specialization level?