# why i must assign one instance of allocator a value?

Tags: c++, traits, allocation, allocator

I got the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542647/allocator-specialized-for-array-types-in-c14) about allocator of array, i show the key code below, and for this question, I have deleted the constructor part, BUT I really don't know why I must assign the value `ra` with `*this`?? and if I just write `ra()`, it will be wrong!

In my opinion, Because the class `array_allocator` is inherited from `std::allocator<T>`, and the copy constructor of `std::allocator` does nothing.

and what is the type of `ra`? I have noticed that
the type is different in c++17 and c++2a, because the "`rebind`" struct have been deleted in c++2a, so in the previous version the type is `std::allocator<int>` , but in c++ 2a, the type is `array_allocator<int>`. as the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tlHx9x) show. so will this influence the result?  I'm very confused, Sorry for my confusing logic. Any answers are welcome :)

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
struct array_allocator : std::allocator<T>
{
    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<C>::value>::type destroy(C * p)
    {
        using U = typename std::remove_extent<C>::type;
        using UAT = typename std::allocator_traits<array_allocator>::template rebind_traits<U>;
        typename std::allocator_traits<array_allocator>::template rebind_alloc<U> ra(*this);  ???

        for (std::size_t i = 0, e = std::extent<C>::value; i != e; ++i)
        {
            UAT::destroy(ra, std::addressof((*p)[e - i - 1]));
        }
    }

    template <typename C, typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<C>::value>::type destroy(C * p)
    {
        p->~C();
    }
};
```