# C++ force new[] to not allocate 4 additional bytes

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2013, new-operator

I'm writing my own memory system in C++ (for performance reasons, additional debugging information, and so that I can allocate memory that is 16-byte aligned), and I am encountering an issue with `new[]`.

It seems that calling `new[]` results in an allocation of an additional 4 bytes indicating the number of elements in the array, which throws off the alignment of all subsequent objects. So my question is this:

Is there any way to turn off the usage of these 4 extra bytes with a compiler flag, `pragma` declaration, etc.?

Here's an example:

```
// Matrix class has to be 16-byte aligned
Matrix* transforms = new( matrixHeap, ALIGN_16, __FILE__, __LINE__ ) Matrix[31];
transforms[0] = Matrix::Identity;
```

When looking in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger, I see these values:

```
returned by new    0x0F468840
transforms         0x0F468844
```

Finally, I take a peek at the raw memory, and I see this:

```
0x0F468840   1F 00 00 00
0x0F468844   01 00 00 00
```

The memory at ******40 is not the first value in `transforms[0]` as expected. Rather, it contains the value `31`.  This means that the matrices are only 4-byte aligned. Is there any way to turn off that array size business so that the first byte of `transforms[0]` ends up in the address returned by new[]?

Here is the important bits of my operator `new[]`:

```
void* operator new[] ( size_t size, Heap* heap, uint32_t alignment, char* file, int lineNumber )
{
    size_t alignedSize = size + alignment - 1;
    void* unalignedPtr = heap->Allocate( alignedSize );
    void* alignedPtr = (void*) (((size_t) unalignedPtr + alignment - 1) & ~(alignment - 1));
    return alignedPtr;
}
```

Comment: C++ needs to know the size of the allocated array. This is a fundamental aspect of the language. Although C++ does not specify that it must be done in this manner, this is a common approach. Try writing a custom container allocator, rather than a `new` allocator.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the alignment issue you're describing. C++ requires that memory returned by `new` must be aligned by the object's alignment requirements.

Comment: Well, I wrote custom new and new[] operators that replace the existing operators, and I ensure that my operators return memory with the alignment I need for the structures I create. My issue is that C++ seems to just magically change the returned value.

Comment: The redundant bytes might be used as a guard. This also provides "metadata" about your allocated memory.

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels Code added

Comment: What is `matrixHeap` ?

Comment: @M.M The Heap type is something I wrote as I was having some issues with Win32 heaps and memory contiguity. For all intents and purposes, the Heap type works just like a Win32 heap, except that all of the memory allocations in my Heap end up in contiguous virtual memory.

Comment: The issue is explained [by this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer) (with `y = 4`). You should also observe that `size` that your `operator new[]` receives is 4 bytes larger than `31*sizeof(Matrix)`.

Comment: You can't change this (not within Standard C++ anyway), the question would be whether it is possible to work around it somehow.  Maybe a more on-point question title would be "How to do custom alignment with  operator new[]()"

Comment: if `sizeof(Matrix)` is a multiple of 16 then you can detect this by inspecting `size % alignment`. If it isn't then you might be out of luck, there is no notion in C++ of an array having stricter alignment requirements than the array elements

Comment: Alright, it is ugly, but I guess I have no choice but to replace my new[] calls with a malloc-style version instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to consistently use 4 bytes for the size, you could just arrange for your `operator new[]` function to return 4 less than a 16-byte aligned address.  You'd still want to have `operator new` return a 16-byte aligned address directly.