# Spamming std::move is the way to go?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

About `std::move`, here is what I can interpret,  according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move :-

- If I want to transfer ownership, I have to call `std::move` (or in rare case, `std::forward`).
- Responsibility of `std::move` is calling `operator=(A&& other)`.
- The most essential step of the move operation is supposed to be implemented in `operator=(A&&)`.
- It is tricky to ensure that `operator=(A&&)` would be called.    It need a special converter.
- There are **only** two converters in the C++ world that can convert variables into `xvalue` (the &&) : `std::move` and `std::forward`.

### **Question**

After adding many of `std::move(std::unique_ptr)` in my code, I start to worry that for such basic feature like transfer ownership, I have to heavily rely on the standard library  (`std::`).

Do I really have to use `std::move` to transfer ownership?

Is spamming and hard-code calling `std::move` in many places of code-base a correct way to go for a high-standard program?

Should `std::move` be encapsulated?

They are actually a single question, but ask in different perspectives.

### Edit

As request, here is my trial & error.  It compiled ok.
I have no problem about the code, but I worry about its approach / pattern.
https://ideone.com/y8Pcgf

```
class T{
    public: int value;
    public: T(int a=1234){
        value = a;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<T> t1 = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(1));
    void* databaseNew=operator new [](sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T>));
    std::unique_ptr<T>* t1ptr=static_cast<std::unique_ptr<T>*>(databaseNew);
    new (t1ptr) std::unique_ptr<T>(std::move(t1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. no, 2. no, 3. yes (and/or move-constructor), 4. no, 5. no

Comment: If you want or need to *explicitly* transfer ownership of an object, then yes you need to use `std::move`. Otherwise let the compiler handle it. Also, what `std::move` actually does is not very much, it is basically a cast of the object to an rvalue reference.

Comment: It is nigh impossible to answer your question as posted. It sounds like you don't understand move semantics and value categories, and are programming by trial and error.  A better idea would be to post an actual [piece of source code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you feel has problems with the use of `std::move` and then we can comment on what you are doing right and wrong.

Comment: @M.M You are correct, I just edited my question to add my trial & error.

Comment: You might also want to [read more about move semantics and what it is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/440558). The two top answers to that question are very detailed and good.

Comment: It's not possible to use "placement operator new[]" like that. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer) for detail.   But supposing you change that to non-array placement new.   Then you only have `t1`, and you `std::move` from `t1` into another object. That's fine.  But you could have omitted `t1` and constructed the placement-new object with the `new T(1)`.

Comment: @M.M What? Are you sure?  With a small modification, I just test it and my program can run correctly without leak.  Hmm.... I may be wrong...

Comment: by "not possible", I mean that there could be buffer overflow introduced by the implementation and you have no reliable way of knowing or working around it, see Howard's answer for detail

Comment: This is a common misconception. `std::move` just shows the programmer's intent to move the callee (by casting it to `&&`), it doesn't do any actual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need to explicitly `move`, of which you complain, was actually done on purpose. Before `unique_ptr`, STL had a horrid construct called `auto_ptr`. It would move ownership impllicitly, and was borderline unusable unless you really really *really* knew what you were doing.

To make things more usable, in most cases C++ now requires you to explicitly state that you intend on moving ownership over a container, by using `std::move`.

In fact, `std::move` is little more than a cast to an rvalue reference.

There are cases where such an explicit specification is not necessary. For example, if the container from which you take ownership is already an rvalue (e.g. - a temporary object), then no case using `std::move` is necessary. For example, the following doesn't compile:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a;
a = new int;
```

But the following does, without needing a move:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a;
a = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int);
```

The reason this does not need a call to `std::move`, despite invoking the move operator, is that the object we move the ownership away from is already a temporary object (i.e. - an rvalue), so no cast is necessary.

Another example is if you call a function that returns a unique_ptr. You might have to call `std::move` inside the function to get it into the return value, but you do not need to call `std::move` on the function's return value to get it into the outside `unique_ptr`. It is already an rvalue, and therefor no cast is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Rule of thumb:

If you're in a deduced x-value context, use `std::forward`:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& t)       // T is deduced x-value, so we forward it
{
  bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Otherwise use `std::move`

```
template<class T>
void foo1(std::vector<T> v)   // although vector<T> is deduced, it's not an x-value
{
    bar(std::move(v));  // so move it
}

template<class T>
void foo2(std::vector<T>&& v)   // although vector<T> is deduced, it's not an x-value. 
                                // In this case an r-value reference
{
    bar(std::move(v));  // so move it
}

template<class T>
void foo3(std::vector<T>& v)   // although vector<T> is deduced, it's not an x-value. 
                               // In this case an l-value reference
{
    bar(std::move(v));  // so move it
}

void foo4(std::vector<int> v)   // complete type
{
    bar(std::move(v));  // so move it
}

void foo5(std::vector<int> const & v)   // const reference
{
    bar(v);  // not much point in moving it. std::move would cast it
             // to std::vector<int> const&&, which although is detectable
             // decays to std::vector<int> const&
}
```

> which although is detectable... what?

It is permissible, if not necessarily advisable to write code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  void foo() const &
  {
    // do one thing...
    std::cout << "one thing\n";
  }

  void foo() const &&
  {
    // do something else...
    std::cout << "or another\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  const X x;
  x.foo();
  std::move(x).foo();
}
```

const r-value references do exist, it's just that no-one uses them because there is no reasonable use-case.

Comment: I am pretty sure people who ask when to use `std::move` don't know when they are in a deduced x-value context.

Comment: @nwp you are of course right. I am hoping the non-x-value examples will offer some insight.