# Crash when initializing a std::string array in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, new-operator

The problem: I am trying to allocate memory for an array of `std::string`, then using `new(...)[]()` to initialize it. Then I try to assign values to the array elements and this causes the application to crash (Access violation). Question is: Am I missing some compiler flag or something obvious?

Compiling this with

```
cl.exe /DEBUG /EHsc /MTd /Zi test.cc
```

produces an executable that crashes (tested in VS 2017 and VS 2012). On a side note it works as expected on Linux with GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
  int a,b;
  S() : a(99), b(299) {}
  S & operator=(const char * rhs) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }  
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const S & s) { os << "(" << s.a << "," << s.b << ")"; return os; }  


typedef std::string T;
//typedef S T;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t N = 100;
    std::allocator<T> mem;
    T * data = mem.allocate(N);
    new(data)T[N]();

    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] = "HELLO WORLD";
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
```

I tried using the other `typedef`, and in that case the initialization works exactly as expected.

EDIT: I see the same crash if I use C `calloc` for allocation instead of `std::allocator`.

SOLVED. It turns out that the problem is this: The C++ standard says that the `new T[N]` expression allocates *at least* `sizeof(T)*N` bytes. Visual C allocates an extra overhead. The placement new `new(ptr)T[N]` assumes that the extra overhead is available in `ptr`.
The solution from the answer below is to loop and construct each item separately.

Comment: Why are you using `std::allocator` and placement `new`? What is the use-case for it? What is the actual problem you try to solve with it? Why can't you use ordinary `new[]`? Why can't you use `std::vector` instead? Your question is a good example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you ask for help with a solution to an (for us) unknown problem.

Comment: Isn't your `T[N]` non-standard C++? (since `N` is not a compile-time constant). Btw, also works using clang compiler under OSX

Comment: @Walter You can use variables when using `new[]`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: The original code was tangled in thousands of lines of recursive templates.

Comment: @UlfW don't forget to accept an answer if it sufficiently answers your question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim that it "works" with GCC is something of an exaggeration:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++      16486983.cpp    -o 16486983
16486983.cpp: In member function ‘S& S::operator=(const char*)’:
16486983.cpp:7:30: warning: unused parameter ‘rhs’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   S & operator=(const char * rhs) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }
                              ^~~
16486983.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
16486983.cpp:20:10: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
     for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
          ^~~~~~~~~
16486983.cpp:20:10: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:38:0,
                 from 16486983.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++config.h:202:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++config.h:202:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
16486983.cpp:20:27: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                           ^
16486983.cpp:22:10: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
     for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
          ^~~~~~~~~
16486983.cpp:22:10: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:38:0,
                 from 16486983.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++config.h:202:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++config.h:202:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
16486983.cpp:22:27: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                           ^
16486983.cpp:14:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
              ^~~~
16486983.cpp:14:28: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
                            ^~~~
```

These need to be fixed; thankfully that's not hard:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
  int a,b;
  S() : a(99), b(299) {}
  S & operator=(const char*) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const S & s) { os << "(" << s.a << "," << s.b << ")"; return os; }


//typedef std::string T;
typedef S T;
int main() {
    std::size_t N = 100;
    std::allocator<T> mem;
    T * data = mem.allocate(N);
    new(data)T[N]();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] = "HELLO WORLD";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Now it runs, almost¹ Valgrind-clean.  But the naked placement-new looks strange - if you're using an allocator, you should use its `construct()`:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    mem.construct(data+i);
```

---

#### ¹Don't forget to release the memory:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    mem.destroy(data+i);
mem.deallocate(data, N);
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be more of a code review than an answer.  But I hope it provides some insight, anyway.  What does Valgrind say on the failing platforms?  That should help diagnose any memory errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the unspecified overhead as described here very well: [Array placement-new requires unspecified overhead in the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer)

A quick fix would be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
  int a,b;
  S() : a(99), b(299) {}
  S & operator=(const char * rhs) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }  
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const S & s) { os << "(" << s.a << "," << s.b << ")"; return os; }  


typedef std::string T;
//typedef S T;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t N = 100;
    std::allocator<T> mem;
    T * datastor = mem.allocate(N+1);
    T * data = new(datastor)T[N]();

    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] = "HELLO WORLD";
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
```

But this is not guaranteed to work always since the "unspecified overhead" might theoretically be larger than `sizeof(std::string)`.

The version without unspecified behavior would new up the elements individually like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
  int a,b;
  S() : a(99), b(299) {}
  S & operator=(const char * rhs) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }  
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const S & s) { os << "(" << s.a << "," << s.b << ")"; return os; }  


typedef std::string T;
//typedef S T;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t N = 100;
    std::allocator<T> mem;
    T * data = mem.allocate(N);
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        new(&data[i]) T();
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i] = "HELLO WORLD";
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        data[i].~T();
    mem.deallocate(data, N);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to use construct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
  int a,b;
  S() : a(99), b(299) {}
  S & operator=(const char * rhs) { a = 100; b = 300; return *this; }
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const S & s) { os << "(" << s.a << "," << s.b << ")"; return os; }


typedef std::string T;
//typedef S T;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t N = 100;
    std::allocator<T> mem;
    T * data = mem.allocate(N);
    //new(data)T[N]();

    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        mem.construct(data + i, "HELLO WORLD");
        //data[i] = "HELLO WORLD";
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The `construct` function will become deprecated in the C++17 standard.

Comment: Using construct instead of new gives me the same crash (i.e. initializing with the default constructor, then assign values to the strings using `operator=`).

Comment: My bad. Using construct seems to work (both Visual C and gcc/linux). I am still not sure what is incorrect about using `new(...)T[]`.

Comment: @UlfW see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer the length is prepended. So `data = new(data)T[N]();` works, if you allocate more than N elements (unspecified overhead)