# Pointer returned by overloaded new is changed

Tags: c++

I have come across a bizarre problem and I have created this simple program in order to demonstrate it. I know the code itself doesn't make much sense, but I would like to highlight something I don't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class tempClass{
public:
    float n;
    tempClass(){};
    ~tempClass(){} //VERY IMPORTANT LINE
    void* operator new[](size_t size);
};


void* tempClass::operator new[](size_t size){
    tempClass* a;
    a= ::new tempClass[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        a[i].n = i*10;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
    return a;
}


int main(){
    tempClass* a;
    a = new tempClass[2];
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << a[0].n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, I have overloaded the operator new for the class that I have created. However, the behaviour of the function changes, depending on whether I include the destructor of the class or not. I have noticed, that if I don't include the destructor, everything works fine, whereas if I did, the returned value of the pointer `a` would be increased by `8` at all times. Therefore, in this example, the last `cout` of the program will print `20` if I include the destructor and `0` if I don't, at all times.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Not the issue by why are you not using `size` in your `operator new[]`?

Comment: As I said in the question, the code doesn't make sense at all. I just wanted to write a dummy example to highlight the problem. Afterall, this is not the only problem that the code has and I am aware of that, but it is easy to highlight the problem through it.

Comment: Do you mean the value of ``a[0].n`` or the pointer ``a``? For the latter I would expect much bigger values. And do you repeat the ``new`` call within the ``main`` function or do you start the whole program several times with different outcome?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a duplicate, but not a homework question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array-new-expressions pass an unspecified amount of overhead to the allocation function (i.e. your `operator new` overload). This is to allow the implementation to record the number of array elements, so that destructors can be called on deletion.

If your implementation detects that the class doesn't *need* destructors to be called (because it is trivially destructible), it may choose to not require the same amount of overhead as it would otherwise.

The formal wording is 8.3.4[expr.new]p11:

> When a *new-expression* calls an allocation function and that allocation has not been extended, the *new-
>   expression* passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type
>   `std::size_t`. **That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater
>   than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array.** [...]

Note that the overhead is *unspecified*, so it could in principle be different at every call! (This is also the reason that [placement-array-new is unusable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425).) However, the Itanium ABI that many implementations use is fairly specific in how the "[array cookie](http://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#array-cookies)" works, and matches your experience.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Itanium CXX ABI [array `operator new[]` cookie](http://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#array-cookies):

> When operator new is used to create a new array, a cookie is usually stored to remember the allocated length (number of array elements) so that it can be deallocated correctly. [...]
>   
>   **No cookie is required if the array element type T has a trivial destructor (12.4 [class.dtor])** [...]

A destructor, other than one defined within the class as `= default`, is non-trivial.