# Is it possible to recreate an array which has been "destroyed" by placement new?

Tags: c++

I was thinking about how to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289394/reusing-a-float-buffer-for-doubles-without-undefined-behaviour) problem with placement new, and I faced a problem.

Suppose, that I allocate a `float` array:

```
float *f = new float[10];
```

Then, I use this storage to store `double`s (note that I assume that `f` is properly aligned, and `sizeof(float)*2==sizeof(double)`), which destroys the float array:

```
double *d = new(f) double;
for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    new(d+i) double;
}
```

Now, is there a way to recreate the float array? The most intuitive solution

```
f = new(f) float[10];
```

may not work, as `new[]` can have a space overhead, so `float[10]` may not fit into `f`.

Comment: What does "recreate" mean? You wish to be able to read the old float values? Or do you just want to scrap the double array and have a float array?

Comment: @Justin: No. As placement `new double` "destroyed" `f`'s original type, I'd like to `f` to have a float array type again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can placement new for arrays be used in a portable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254/can-placement-new-for-arrays-be-used-in-a-portable-way)

Comment: The best reason you ask this is it's an XY problem. With the benefit of doubt, I consider this question unclear. Please state what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Olaf: I've described the background in the first sentence. It is absolutely plausible, that one wants to create a function, which has `float *` input/output, and the function wants to use this buffer as a temporary buffer to store doubles to avoid unnecessary allocation. Not an XY problem.

Comment: Can't you use a loop as you did with the doubles ?

Comment: Which function? There is no function shown in your code. It seems more like a fundamental missunderstanding of the `new` operator and language basics. But thanks for removing my doubts.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: no, because it wouldn't make it a float array, but floats sitting next to each other. These are not the same.

Comment: They were floats sitting next to each other. The overhead area is before the position the pointer points to. That hasn't changed. Truth to tell, it is hardly necessary, I doubt any compiler runs a destructor on integral types and even less that it would choke on an illegal float representation.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: yes, considering practice, you are right. But this question is more about the standard, which for some reason, not that strict about this matter, allows overhead, which even can be differing size for each new[] call.

Comment: Ok but then, reintepret_cast your double* to float* an do a placement new on each element and you'll get the same original state.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: yes, that would be a logical thing to do, but I don't think that I'll get the same state. As I've said, an array is not just objects sitting next to each other. `new(f) float[2];` differs from `new(f) float; new(f+1) float;`.

Comment: We are still paying the decision to not make array first class citizen but not that much. The standard guarantees you the contiguity of member (albeit with padding) in arrays. This is true whether the array is allocated on the stack or by new. The only twist is the overhead to relate the number of object between new[] and delete[] (plus whatever is needed by implementation). But placement new of single object doesn't have the overhead and memory area referenced by pointer offset can hold them. I don't see how you come up with additional constraints.

Comment: What does it mean to "destroy" the type of the array?  Isn't `f` still `float*` no matter what you do with it?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: for example, you cannot index a pointer, if it is not pointing to an actual array. So, if `f` points to two consecutive floats, created by 2 two placement new, you **cannot** use `f[1]` to get the second one. That's what the standard says. It is because `f` doesn't point to an actual array.

Comment: @geza please see 7.6.1.1 `[...]The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))[...]`. Placement new doesn't change that. The only case it would appear is if you tried to do placement new of an array insided the elements of the array (as an array of array) ; this is a consequence of 7.6.2.4/15 (where overhead x applies only to placement new of array). But the overall array stays the same - unfortunately, we could have implemented a realloc of arrays.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: yes, but: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4. Pointer addition is defined only if the pointer points to an array. Some further thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498585/is-adding-to-a-char-pointer-ub-when-it-doesnt-actually-point-to-a-char-arr

Comment: `new(f+i*2) double;` is undefined because the lifetime of the whole float array is finished when you create the first `double`.

Comment: @xskxzr: whoa, good catch :) I hopefully fixed it.

Comment: @geza Sorry, I miss your point about 7.6.6/4. It only states that `If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object` then it is UB to go outside the bounds of the array. It doesn't say that pointer arithmetic is limited to array. And the discussion you mention is the difference between struct member offsets vs array; this doesn't apply here.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: the standard defines what happens, if `p` points to an array. If it doesn't point to an array, it is not defined at all. So I think it is UB.

Comment: @geza 7.6.6/4 gives you the general rule `When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand.` This is not UB.