# Dynamic arrays in C++ without Undefined Behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

After learning that std::vector is unimplementable in pure C++, I was wondering if it is possible to write a dynamic array without evoking UB.
We can't do pointer arithmetic [without an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451770/treating-memory-returned-by-operator-newsizeoft-n-as-an-array), which implies we cannot have a dynamic buffer with partially initizalized memory and treat it as an array; so std::vector must rely on the implementation defining some behavior where it would otherwise be UB.

Dynamic arrays are pretty ubiquitious data structures, and generally simple. The seemed impossibility of being able to implement this conformantly makes C++ seem like a not-so-general-purpose system language, IMO.

As so, my questions are:

- How one can write a dynamic array (a mundane one, not necessarily a Container) in C++ (without using std::vector) that conforms to the standard?
- How can such implementation be made space-time efficient (preferably without UB or implementation specific behavior)?

N.B.: **dynamic array** is used here to denote a linear data structure that can grow/shrink "in place", like a std::vector or, similarly, a C buffer (m)alloced in the heap.

Comment: First time I heard that std::vector is unimplementable in pure C++.  Can you provide a reference so I can get up to speed?

Comment: @davidbak There's a link in the question.

Comment: @davidbak I have no references to the standard right now but as Asteroids With Wings mentioned, I linked to a question on SO that mentions this.

Comment: OK. Answers at that link strongly suggest that the problem is a bug in the standard which doesn't reflect the actual intent (or actual practice).  So, is this the premise for this question?  That the bug in the standard won't be fixed anytime soon and in the meantime some hypothetical compiler will take advantage of it and cause anyone's std::vector, no matter how implemented, to erase your hard disk due to UB?

Comment: @davidbak I believe that is the cause of the OP's concern here, yes, so I addressed the question from that perspective in my answer below.

Comment: @davidbak We believe the intention is to make implementations work but if it's a bug then it should be fixed. As for how compilers deal with it is not relevant in the context of UB.

Comment: @Nazinho It is relevant when you're asking how to do something in practice. This particular UB falls into the category of "standard wording oversight", not into the category of "omg never do this in your program it's something the compiler will assume you don't do". This is real life so you have to have a little flexibility. That being said I vaguely recall a proposal that _may_ be relevant; still trying to find it.

Comment: @Nazinho: "*but if it's a bug then it should be fixed*" But it's not a bug in code; it's not a bug in your compiler or your program. It's a bug in a piece of paper. You can't "unwrite" a specification; you can only ever create a new version that more directly matches the intent. And the changes will presumably not require the compiler or the programs written against it to change. I'm not saying that it's unimportant, but I think you're highly *exaggerating* its importance.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: "*still trying to find it*" You probably mean [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r5.html).

Comment: @NicolBolas This is what I meant by "fix". Perhaps a better word would be revise.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you, yes. For some reason I can never find good keywords to search for it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: The C Standard was written at a time when the only time anyone would care whether the Standard required implementations to do something would be when there would be a practical advantage to having some implementation do something else, and its authors thus made no effort to ensure that it mandated corner cases where there would be no imaginable reason for compilers to do anything weird.  Some parts of the C++ Standard are based upon the C Standard and still embody that philosophy.  Whether or not it's a "defect" depends upon the Standard's intended purpose.

Comment: @supercat That was decades ago. Times change. It's a defect. An actual thing in the standard library has undefined behaviour. Doesn't really matter what the intention was: you fix the defect to remove ambiguity. Obviously the authors of P0593 (who are well-reknowned) agree.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: According to the authors of the Standard, as documented in the published Rationale, one of the purposes of "Undefined Behavior" was to identify areas of "conforming language extension" by allowing implementations to define useful behaviors for constructs that are "officially" undefined.  The question of *when* implementations should support "popular extensions" is a quality-of-implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  What has changed is that the cost of supporting such "popular extensions" in cases where they would be useful is no longer zero.

Comment: In many cases, the cost of supporting such extensions would be far less than the cost of having user code work around their absence, but the Standards expect compiler writers and their customers to be better able to weigh such issues than the Committee ever could.  What is needed is not for the Committee to try to make cost-benefit judgments, but rather for them to supply means by which programmers can indicate what semantics their program requires, with implementations being free to either support those semantics or reject the programs.  Certain parts of the C and C++ standards...

Comment: ...would need to be rewritten to allow many kinds of tasks to be accomplished without reliance upon "officially" Undefined Behavior.  Among other things, rather than allowing for certain kinds of optimizations to be performed despite the fact that their effects might be observable, the Standards presently treat almost all cases where the effects of an optimization might be observable as UB, *even in cases where the effects would otherwise be benign*.  Consider, for example, the effect of `struct foo *p, a, b; a=p[i]; b=p[j];` in a case where some of the storage for `p[i]` or `p[j]`...

Comment: ...hasn't been written since the last time it was used as some other type, but the corresponding elements of `a` and `b` will never be examined.  If a compiler "knows" what was in `p[i]` before the storage was used as some other type, it might load `a` with that, even if the actual storage no longer holds that value.  If it doesn't know that `j` happens to equal `i`, it might load `b` with the actual contents of the storage.  Allowing a programmer to say that a compiler need not ensure that `a` reflects the actual contents of storage, but mustn't do anything else wonky as a result of the...

Comment: ...parts of `*p` that were last written as a different type would make it possible for a compiler to generate more efficient code than would be possible if the only way to keep execution on the rails was to explicitly initialize all parts of `*p` including those that code would never care about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `std::vector` can't, then you can't either.

But I wouldn't worry about it. This is one of those cases where people have found a problem with the wording of the standard, that *technically* makes an extremely common use case undefined. But your vectors still work.

Now, the key: that's not because of magic innate to `std::vector`, or to some particular `std::vector` implementation: it's because the compiler doesn't perform absurd optimisations that make use of this undefined behaviour that somebody only just spotted while studying the text with a fine-toothed comb.

Perhaps it'll be tidied up [in a future revision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r5.html), but for practical purposes you do not need to worry about it, whether you use `std::vector` or you use `new[]`.

Comment: That's probably the pragmatical POV. _Perhaps it'll be tidied up in a future revision, but for practical purposes you do not need to worry about it, whether you use std::vector or you use new[]._ can you please provide some insight for whether there's some discussion on this?

Comment: I've added a link to a relevant proposal with plenty of discussion and rationale (thanks Nicol for getting me the link)

Answer (score 5):

> dynamic array is used here to denote a linear data structure that can grow/shrink "in place",

You can't. It is precisely the growing/shrinking in-place that makes `vector` unimplementable in C++17.

The problem is that the C++17 object model recognizes "array" as a thing, a special object type with its own properties. Pointer arithmetic recognizes arrays and works within them. But an "array" has a specific element count, and merely creating a live object of the array element type at the end of the array doesn't actually make the array longer. Which means pointer arithmetic doesn't work to access this newly created object.

That problem doesn't go away just because you change the wrapper. It is a problem which is fundamental to the idea of being able to make an array bigger and smaller, while still having pointer arithmetic work.

Comment: What this mean in pratice? Is such inconsistency irrelevant for pratical applications?

Comment: @Nazinho: "*Is such inconsistency irrelevant for pratical applications?*" For this case? Yes.

Comment: Where overlooking this can cause trouble?

Comment: @Nazinho: Pretty much nowhere. I don't understand your question.