# Understanding C++ Standard's interpretation of "object creation", "object type" and differences with C

Tags: c++, c, c++11, object, language-lawyer

I have recently started reading `C++` standard ([n337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/)) to better understand the language and avoid pitfalls associated with `UB`. I know this might be a very basic question, frankly however I haven't found a good answer explaining these concepts very well. Maybe everyone understands it and I don't.

Consider following text from **[intro.object]/1**

> An object is a region of storage. [...] An object is created by a definition (3.1),

Ok. **[basic.def]/2** covers in detail what is a definition.

> by the implementation (12.2) when needed.

I am guessing temporaries created are covered as part of this.

> by a new-expression (5.3.4) or

**[expr.new]** covers this, though I haven't read it yet.

Further **[basic.life]/1** states:

> The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> — storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and

Now consider following example:

```
int *x = (int*)(operator new (10*sizeof(int)));         // (1a) How many objects are created? Does allocated storage has a type?
::new ((void*)x) int[10]{};                             // (2a) How many objects are created? What is/are the type/s?
```

Regarding (1a), I think it's One. `x` is created with a type of `int *`.
The allocation of storage doesn't constitue object creation and type is property of an object.

Regarding (2a), I think it's Ten objects of type `int`.
Also, since the pointer returned is to the first object, would it be well-defined to access other 9 objects using pointer arithmetic?
Does this also mean that if I know that an object of type `T` is located at an address `A`, I can use cast to access the value of object and it's well-defined?

```
// How many objects does (1b) & (2b) create? What is/are the type/s?
// Does (1b) or (2b) invoke UB because of those extra 3 bytes?
int *y = (int*)(operator new (10*sizeof(int) + 3));     // (1b) - notice extra "+ 3" as part of size
::new ((void*)y) int[10]{};                             // (2b)
```

Is "placement new" the only way of constructing/reusing dynamically allocated objects in `C++`?

Since `C` doesn't have "placement new" for constructing objects after allocation is done, is `C++` compatible with `C` in this regard? Is an `object` in `C` the same as in `C++` (barring the fact that `C++` has class types)?
How is **object creation** for dynamically allocated objects (and determining their type) in `C++` different from `C`?

Comment: https://wg21.link/p0593 - The paper covers the state of affairs up to C++20, as well as the C++20 approach to fixing the issue.

Comment: There's also this highly related Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451770/treating-memory-returned-by-operator-newsizeoft-n-as-an-array

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Thanks for the links, shall go through them.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the problem is that a wrong answer is accepted

Comment: _An object is a region of storage_ Not true for a long time :)