# Is it well-formed to do pointer arithmetic on a pointer returned from an allocator?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, pointer-arithmetic

I'm aware that this question has already been asked and somewhat answered in the past.
However, I've a doubt on a detail that hasn't been cleared out yet (or at least for which I couldn't find a QA).

Consider the following code:

```
T *mem = allocator_traits::allocate(allocator, 10);
allocator_traits::construct(allocator, mem+1, params...);
```

I'm constructing an object at `mem[1]` even if the object at `mem[0]` doesn't exist yet.
As far as I understand, pointer arithmetic is well defined over a created array of not-constructed objects. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451770/treating-memory-returned-by-operator-newsizeoft-n-as-an-array#) QA doesn't answer this specific case:

> I should have stated that when I said storage + i will be well-defined under P0593, I was assuming that the elements storage[0], storage[1], ..., storage[i-1] have already been constructed. Although I'm not sure I understand P0593 well enough to conclude that it wouldn't also cover the case where those elements hadn't already been constructed.

In other terms, the author says that this could be UB. On the other side, it would make it impossible for an `std::vector` implementation to do something like this:

```
buf_end_size = newbuf + sizeof(T) * size();
```

Since I expect it to be valid code (and I've seen this in some implementations), it would mean that pointer arithmetic is well defined for any value of `i` also when objects aren't constructed.

So, my question is: is this UB or I can safely do pointer arithmetic on the pointer returned by `allocate` in any case, for example if I want to construct the element at position 1 before that at position 0? Also, does the answer change between C++17 and C++20?

Comment: `std::vector` (`std::` in general) might use stuff which would  be illegal for regular users.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, ignore the comment about vector. :)

Comment: C++20 introduces [Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](https://oleksandrkvl.github.io/2021/04/02/cpp-20-overview.html#fix-impl-creation); `newbuf + sizeof(T) * size()` seems possible, but legit of `mem+1` might depends of `T`.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is valid not only when an array elements outside lifetime, but even when the whole array is.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer can you point out the wording in the standard or provide more details?

Comment: @Jarod42 well, the _problem_ remains for non trivially constructible types, doesn't it?

Comment: Neither https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.array nor https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#4 (not anything else) require objects to be within lifetime.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer though, they require pointer arithmetic to operate on an array of existing elements and in my case some elements don't exist. So, it's still ambiguous or I'm missing something from your answer/reasoning.

Comment: What do you mean by «don't exist»? Operations which implicitly create arrays, implicitly create their elements, but don't start the lifetimes of the elements if they are not of implicit-lifetime types. At least, this is the intent of P0593. See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#10.note-1

Comment: @LanguageLawyer so, it creates but doesn't construct the elements? Therefore, pointer arithmetic doesn't depend on the lifetime of the objects in the array? Is this valid for both trivially and non trivially constructible types? Makes sense to me, I'm just trying to figure out what the wording is for that and whether it is UB or not.

Comment: _so, it creates but doesn't construct the elements?_ Yes. _Is this valid for both trivially and non trivially constructible types?_ An array type is always implicit-lifetime type, for any element type. _Makes sense to me, I'm just trying to figure out what the wording is for that_ https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#10.sentence-2 may be confusing as suggesting that only objects of ILT are created (so, non-ILT array elements are not created). But I think this relies on an unspecified rule that creating an object == creating all its subobjects.

Comment: Doesn't [the point immediately after](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#11) bind the implicit creation to the validity of pointers? Has this something to do with pointer arithmetic and non-ILT array elements? That's where my mind blew up.

Comment: If you have smth like `auto p = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));` and then use `p` as a pointer to the first element of array `int[4]` (or, maybe, only as `int[3]` or `int[2]`), `malloc` will: 1) create such array; 2) produce a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @skypjack u ok?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer what do you mean? I'm... Almost convinced, yeah.

Comment: Convinced of what?

Comment: This may require digging further into allocator and backend code for constructor which nobody really wants to do.

I find this unnecessary for any real-world use and not important. Just construct the object like you normally do. We start at index 0 and specify length or size. Keep it simple.

Comment: @Cornel: It's a [tag:language-lawyer] question, so the relevance to "real-world use" is irrelevant :)  This also means that the code used in any given implementation is also irrelevant; the question is what the standard demands.

Comment: To think about it, if we couldn't use arythmetics,then whole point of placement new would be moot. We wouldn't be able to calculate the pointer to pass to new-expression.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of incorrect terminology in this discussion.  There is no "create but not construct".  The correct phrasing is "obtain storage" without having (yet) created an object.  The controlling rule is https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6 and it only allows use of pointers "as if the pointer were of type `void*`", which excludes pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a relevant text in the standard about pointer arithmetic. Basically if you do addition/subtraction between two pointers and the result does not go out of bound of a reserved array, then the behavior is well-defined. I believe what you are trying to do is well-defined, because you have reserved an array of memory.

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5

Comment: Also relevant is that [T* allocate\(size_t n\) returns a pointer to the first element of an array of n T's](https://eel.is/c++draft/memory#allocator.members-3). This is indeed well-defined, and perfectly valid.