# Legality of using `T` pointer derived from aliased `byte` pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

In C++, it's legal for a `char`, `unsigned char`, or [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) pointer to alias any `T` pointer. Such aliased pointer is capable of accessing the object's representation in raw memory.

My question is whether it's legal and free of undefined-behavior to *use* a `T*` pointer derived from arithmetic on a `char`/`unsigned char`/`std::byte` pointer aliasing an original `T` array object sequence -- provided that the resultant pointer is still aligned correctly and within the original reachability of the aliased sequence.
As a concrete example:

```cpp
// Array sequence is 2 in length
auto array = std::array<unsigned,2>{0xdead, 0xbeef};

// Derive the address of &array[1] using std::byte pointer
auto p  = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(array.data());
auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(p + sizeof(unsigned));

assert(p1 == &array[1]); // This expression should be legal since the pointer is safely derived
assert(*p1 == array[1]); // But is this legal, as per the C++ standard?
```

The pointer `p1` should be safely derived in the above example since it doesn't exceed the reachability of `array`'s bound. I know that in many cases in C++ it's legal to cast a pointer to a type/representation that can't actually be used/dereferenced. Is the resultant pointer here legal to *dereference* as far as the standard is concerned?

For the purpose of this question, assume that `T` may not be standard-layout type.

**Note:** I'm not asking about whether this will work *in practice*, since I have yet to see this type of code fail on compilers; but I'm curious to know whether this is, strictly-speaking, legal per the C++ standard.

---

**Edit:**

I'd rather not derail this question, but there are a few comments that are asserting that `p + sizeof(unsigned)` is undefined behavior as a result of [[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add), in particular quoting both [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#4) and [[expr.add]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#6) due to `p` not actually being a byte-array.

There is, in fact, a byte sequence<sup>[1]</sup>, and both [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#4) and [[expr.add]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#6) simply do not apply<sup>[2]</sup>

[1]: `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` view the **object representation** of an object, which is defined under [[basic.types.general]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types.general#4) as being:

> The object representation of an object of type `T` is the sequence of `N` `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where `N` equals `sizeof(T)`.

The above means that there *is* a formal sequence of `unsigned char` (which `std::byte` is capable of representing), which means `p + sizeof(unsigned)` is valid. We aren't viewing through a similar pointer, we are viewing exactly as the underlying object-representation which is legal.

[2]: [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#4) is simply referring to reachability of array objects. However, as pointed out above, there *is* a valid and reachable object due to the `unsigned char` sequence, and we do not exceed reachability -- thus this doesn't apply as a case of undefined behavior.

As far as I can tell, [[expr.add]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#6) primarily exists to avoid cases where an array of derived types is cast to a base pointer and attempted to be indexed. However it wouldn't apply in this case because we aren't viewing through a "similar" pointer, we are viewing an object representation that is formally defined *as* a sequence of `unsigned char`s. This isn't a similar representation, it's exact.

Comment: Good question. I think it is intended to be legal, because otherwise you cannot implement C-style `qsort` or `bsearch`, and the standard most certainly does not intend to disallow writing code like that. Whether it contains an actual permission, I don't know.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. `qsort` is a function provided by the C library, isn't it? This basically means, its source code needs to be translated with a C compiler, not a C++ one. My point is that if I write a C function, which might be then eventually called from C++ code, I don't need to follow the C++ rules.

Comment: [expr.add] reads: *... Otherwise, if `P` points to an array element `i` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element `i+j` of `x` if `0≤i+j≤n` and the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element `i−j` of `x` if `0≤i−j≤n`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.* But formally there is no array of `std::byte`s at `p`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I didn't say "C qsort", I said "C-style qsort". You may want to implement a perfectly good C++ sorting routine using this style.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you? This will basically work only for _trivially-copyable_ types (as `qsort` works). What will this be good for in C++? BTW, reasoning that you "wouldn't be able to do something" is hardly a reason that it's legal (IMO). Please, note that this is a _language-lawyer_ question, which means OP is asking about legality with respect to C++ standrads, not whether implementations typically support it.

Comment: Related question: [Treating memory returned by `operator new(sizeof(T) * N)` as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451770/treating-memory-returned-by-operator-newsizeoft-n-as-an-array).

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, you will need to supply a swap function in addition to a comparison function.  Or just restrict it to work with trivially copyable types. There is nothing wrong with writing code this way. If a language rule makes a perfectly ordinary library function "magic" so that the programmer cannot legally supply an alternative implementation, then this rule is highly suspect. Not that it cannot exist by laws of natur or logic. There are no such laws that cover the C++ standard. I'm saying you need a pretty darn good rationale to have such a rule.

Comment: @DanielLangr AFAICT the community has always considered the spirit of the law, a.k.a. the intent of the standard, no less important than the letter of the law. If there is a contradiction between the spirit and the letter, then there is a defect that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _Good question. I think it is intended to be legal, because otherwise you cannot implement C-style qsort or bsearch_ Library functions need not be implementable in C.

Comment: `p + sizeof(unsigned)` violates [expr.add]/6

Comment: @Evg _But formally there is no array of `std::byte`s at `p`_ There is no problem with this from the POV of the quote you posted, since the quote doesn't say that there must be array of `T` if pointer is of type `T*`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "`p + sizeof(unsigned)` violates [expr.add]/6" -- You are mistaken. `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` can view the object representation of an object, and said representation is defined in [basic.types.general/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types.general#4) as being a sequence of bytes up to `N`, where `N` is `sizeof(T)`. Such addressing is legal since there _is_ a byte-array **as the object's representation**. Formally, there *is* a byte array, and so this is not in violation of [expr.add]/6

Comment: Sequence ≠ array. And even if there were array of `unsigned char`: 1) you are not obtaining a pointer to and element of this array. 2) even if you obtained it, you would still violate [expr.add]/6, since `unsigned char` and `std::byte` are not similar types.

Comment: _[expr.add]/6 primarily exists to avoid cases where an array of derived types is cast to a base pointer and attempted to be indexed._ It avoids such case only if you have some complicated inheritance graph (with multiple or virtual inheritance). If you get a pointer to a base class subobject, you won't violate [expr.add]/6 by doing arithmetic on such pointer.

Comment: _However it doesn't apply in this case because we aren't viewing through a "similar" pointer, we are viewing an object representation that is formally defined as an array of unsigned chars. This isn't a similar representation, it's exact._ This suggests that you don't know what [similar type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.qual#def:similar_types) is.

Comment: `std::arrray<T, N>` is not guaranteed to store an array. Neither that `.data()` gives you a pointer which points to array element. So, why did you chose to use `std::array` instead of ordinary array?