# Problem using malloc() for C++ string object in VC++, but no problem with new

Tags: c++, visual-c++, malloc, new-operator

Here is a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct Car{
    std::string model;
} Car;

std::string get_model() {
    std::string str = "Maserati";
    return str;
}

int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;
    //Car *list = new Car[nCars];                   // works everywhere g++/VC++
    Car *list = (Car *)malloc(nCars * sizeof(Car)); // works in g++, not VC++

    list[0].model = get_model();
    std::cout << "model=" << list[0].model << std::endl;    
    // delete[] list;
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no problem when I used malloc() or new in g++. However, malloc() does not work in Visual C++. Should I use new always when I allocate the C++ class object?

(a debtor)<><

Comment: Do not use `malloc` in C++, it does not call the constructor, therefore the objects are invalid.

Comment: There were problems with g++ too, but the nature of undefined behaviour is that it doesn’t always produce an immediately observable effect.

Comment: I suggest you free *list (or ev. delete it using new) for sake of completeness/elegance.

Comment: Molbdnilo, that's what I observed. Thanx. 

L.C, let me add free() for completeness, as you suggested. Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating memory without calling a constructor or calling the destructor when the object is about to be removed. This is what `new[]` and `delete[]` does for you, so use them - or better yet, use smart pointers - or even better, a standard container, like `std::vector` to keep the objects for you.

Your code with the missing parts added:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Car {
    std::string model;

    Car() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~Car() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;

    // allocate memory
    Car *list = (Car *)malloc(nCars * sizeof(Car));

    // manually calling constructors
    for(int i=0; i<nCars; ++i) {
        new(&list[i]) Car();
    }

    // use objects here

    // manually calling destructors
    for(int i=0; i<nCars; ++i) {
        list[i].~Car();
    }

    // freeing memory
    free(list);
}
```

Compare with using `new[]` and `delete[]`:

```
int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;

    // create cars
    Car* list = new Car[nCars];

    // use objects here

    // delete cars
    delete[] list;
}
```

Compare with using a container:

```
int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;

    // create cars
    std::vector<Car> list(nCars);

    // use objects here
}
```

Comment: The rule of thumb is to use new if C++ objects involved. It is simpler. Thanx.

Comment: If the choice is between `malloc/free` and `new/delete`, then yes! But `new/delete` should also be avoided if you can. You can almost always replace them with a container or smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) that will destroy the elements even if an exception occurs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

While it is wrong to say, "Never use `malloc()` in C++," it is definitely true that you should never use `malloc()` to instantiate a class.

Keep in mind that C++ is, in a sense, a hybrid language in that it effectively supports an almost complete subset of C and adds the superset of C++ functionality.  `malloc()` has a role to play when using built-in types like `int`, `char`, `float`, etc.

For objects, however, `new` must be used.  It might be true that you have found that `malloc()` works in many cases, but `new` and `delete` will cause constructors and destructors to be called, which will *never* happen with `malloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score -3):

The problem here is because you're allocating a memory for the std::string of your Car struct but do not call the std::string constructor.

You should call a placement new for each item in the array to call the constructor and initialize the std::string field in the Car struct:

```
int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;
    Car* list = (Car *)malloc(nCars * sizeof(Car));

    for (int i = 0; i < nCars; ++i)
        new(&list[i])Car();

    list[0].model = get_model();
    std::cout << "model=" << list[0].model << std::endl;
}
```

-- ORIGINAL ANSWER --

Here's my original answer (which is inorrect due to an extra overhead that may be required for arrays: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation)

If you have to use malloc then I suggest you use a in-place constructor with the returned memory block:

```
int main() {
    const int nCars = 2;
    Car *list = new (malloc(nCars * sizeof(Car)))Car[nCars];

    list[0].model = get_model();
    std::cout << "model=" << list[0].model << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new (malloc(/*...*/)) class-type[/*...*/]`: this is heresy! I wouldn't suggest it :D

Comment: Please don't. This is another UB and memory leak piled *on top* of the original snippet.

Comment: Yes. Basically, you don't know [how much space needs a placement new on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425/5470596).

Comment: Thanks @YSC. I've updated my answer now but kept the original one as a warning :) Can you see any reason why a per-item placement new won't work here?