# I try to use placement new, but always complies error

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, placement-new

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <new>
    
    const int BUF = 512;
    const int N = 5;
    char buffer[BUF];

    int main(){
        using namespace std;
    

        double *pd1, *pd2;
        int i;
        cout << "Calling new and placement new: \n";
        pd1 = new double[N];
        pd2 = new (buffer) double[N];
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            pd2[i] = pd1[i] = 1000 + 20.0 * i;
        }
        cout << "Memory addresses:\n" << " heap: " << pd1
            << " static: " << (void *)buffer << endl;
        cout << "Memory contents:\n";
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            cout << pd1[i] << " at " << &pd1[i] << "; ";
            cout << pd2[i] << " at " << &pd2[i] << endl;
        }
        delete [] pd1;
        return 0;
}
```

newplace.cpp:15:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new [](sizetype, char [512])’
pd2 = new (buffer) double[N];

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/fYG3nY). This program compiles and runs for me.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Comment: Maybe it's just a matter of the complier, which works in my Visual Studio IDE.Thanks

Comment: Please compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and show the *exact* error messages obtained in your question, as an [mre]. See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Explain in your question what forbids you from using standard [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). **Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)**

Comment: `pd2 = new (buffer) double[N];` This is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720425/array-placement-new-requires-unspecified-overhead-in-the-buffer)!