# C++ moving a unique_ptr to a struct member

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, stdmove

I have the following program -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Person
{
   public:
      Person(const std::string& name):
         name(name) { }

      ~Person() { std::cout << "Destroyed" << std::endl; }

      std::string name;
};

typedef struct _container
{
   std::unique_ptr<Person> ptr;
}CONTAINER;

void func()
{
   CONTAINER* c = static_cast<CONTAINER*>(malloc(sizeof(CONTAINER)));
   std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person("FooBar"));
   c->ptr = std::move(p);
   std::cout << c->ptr->name << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
   func();
   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

The program prints "FooBar". I expect the program to print "Destroyed" when func() return but it does not. Can someone help me with why that would not be happening in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've actually got undefined behaviour here. 
You cant just cast a malloc'd buffer to an object type. The constructors are never called and your member variables are in an invalid state.

You need to do either:

```
void func()
{
   CONTAINER c;
   std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person("FooBar"));
   c.ptr = std::move(p);
   std::cout << c.ptr->name << std::endl;
}
```

Or

```
void func()
{
   CONTAINER * c = new CONTAINER();
   std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person("FooBar"));
   c->ptr = std::move(p);
   std::cout << c->ptr->name << std::endl;
   delete c;
}
```

or if you really want to use malloc - you'll need to use placement new to get the right behaviour - but usually you dont want that, so I  wont elaborate for now...

Answer (score 2):

You forget to add this line at the end of `func()`.

```
delete c;
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/MgoYSJ) is the test (ideone).

`c` is a raw pointer.  It is not a smart pointer.
Thus, you have to delete it manually.

Deleting `c` will automatically delete `CONTAINER::ptr` because `CONTAINER::ptr` is a unique pointer.

However, you have `malloc` yourself, the more proper code might be :-

```
c->~_container();
```

Then `free()`, but I don't think it is needed in this case, because `CONTAINER` is not on a heap.
( I have never used `malloc`, so I am not sure about this part. )

**Edit:**
My solution is a quick patch to solve a single problem.  (not print "Destroyed")
Please also read ***Michael Anderson***'s solution.
It addresses another *underlying* issue of the OP's code. (malloc)

**Edit2:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254/can-placement-new-for-arrays-be-used-in-a-portable-way) is a good link about placement new that ***Michael Anderson*** mentioned.
The code below is copied from the link (with little modification):-

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  const int NUMELEMENTS=20;
  char *pBuffer = new char[NUMELEMENTS*sizeof(A)];  
  //^^^ difference : your "CONTAINER" could be char[xxxx] (without new)
  A *pA = (A*)pBuffer;
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMELEMENTS; ++i) {
    pA[i] = new (pA + i) A();
  }
  printf("Buffer address: %x, Array address: %x\n", pBuffer, pA);
  // dont forget to destroy!
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMELEMENTS; ++i){
    pA[i].~A();
  }  
  delete[] pBuffer;//<--- no need to delete char[] if it is a stack variable
  return 0;
}
```

For further detail, please see that above link (because I don't want to copy more of it  to here).

Here is another useful link : [Using malloc in C++ is generally not recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Comment: Ah, I see. Since the malloc'd area is not "smart", the program does not track  'c' the same way it tracks the scope of the unique pointer.

Comment: Nope - its worse than this, casting a malloc'd buffer to a type that has constructor is undefined behaviour - and the program is allowed to produce whatever garbage it likes.

Comment: @Michael Anderson  Thank.  I must say that I agree with you.